# How to enable UISplitViewController's preferredDisplayMode = .primaryOverlay setting for iPhone size class

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to use the `UISplitViewController` for iPhone portrait mode (since it will use navigation controller instead).

I tried to set the `UISplitViewController`'s `preferredDisplayMode = .primaryOverlay` (which let user to swipe in/out master view from the left).  However, this setting only works for iPad and Plus. iPhone still keep using navigation controller, ignoring my setting.

My question is - how to use `UISplitViewController` for iPhone? I see that Outlook iOS app can do this so it should be possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `UISplitViewController` only works on iPads. On iPhone it acts like a master/detail view controller. If you want that UI style for iPhone you'll have to implement it yourself.